# Django migration issue.

Tags: python, django

I created a django application so along the line I wanted to reset the entire database so I deleted the database and deleted all migration files. it is not the first time I have done such which I assume is not a bad way of doing it. so I ran the command like `python manage.py makemigrations` and I got this error in my terminal

```
 django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: 
Migration auth.0009_user_following dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'profiles', u'0001_initial')
```

I am totally confused and I dont have any idea on what to do next. HELP

Comment: How can you migrate if you have nothing to migrate from? :o

Comment: sorry I am lost what was I suppose to do.

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` this gives the same error

Comment: how does your model file look?

Comment: I have multiple applications so I do not know the model you talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a custom migrations in your generic app auth, just delete the file:

```
VIRTUALENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/auth.0009_user_following
```

Comment: I have a question. I created a following and unfollowing app. initially users can follow each other but later I realized it was not working again and those that have been followed can not be unfollowed again. this was why I deleted the database initially. any thing I can do?

Comment: 2) can I delete all the migrations present in this location `VIRTUALENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/`

Comment: then mark the question as accepted.

1. it depends of your code, how do you follow someone ?
2. Absolutely not, you will break django if you do it

Comment: This is the link to my code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880197/django-ajax-follow-and-unfollow?noredirect=1#comment78746103_45880197

Comment: Hi @uswe2021091 I need you help regarding a question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263867/creating-relationship-between-two-apps-in-django

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this to get the initial migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <nameofyourapp>
```

Then run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thanks tho but fixed