# django like button counting irregularly

Tags: jquery, django

I have a django application where I implemented a like button for posts posted on the blog. I recently discovered that when ever a like button is clicked by a registered user, the like increases exceedingly. Instead of the number of likes to get increased by 1 it increases by maybe 90+ and when the button is clicked agin for it to change to unlike it still increases so the like function becomes uneven. Below is my code for the like function

**Html**

```
{% with total_likes=obj.likes.count likes=obj.likes.all %}
      <span class="count">
      <span class="total">{{ total_likes }}</span>
        like{{ total_likes|pluralize }} </span>
      <a href="#" data-id="{{ obj.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in likes %}un{% endif %}like" class="like button">

               {% if request.user not in users_like %}
               like
                {% else %}
                unlike
                {% endif %}
      </a>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
  var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
      // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
      return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method)); }
        $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) { xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        } }
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('a.like').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
$.post('{% url "posts:like" %}',
  {
    id: $(this).data('id'),
    action: $(this).data('action')
  }, function(data){
    if (data['status'] == 'ok') {
      var previous_action = $('a.like').data('action');
  // toggle data-action
  $('a.like').data('action', previous_action == 'like' ? 'unlike' : 'like');
  // toggle link text
  $('a.like').text(previous_action == 'like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like');
  // update total likes
var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
  $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
    } }
); });

  });
  </script>
```

**Views**

```
def post_likes(request):
    post_id = request.POST.get('id')
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    if post_id and action:
        try:
            instance = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            if action == 'like':
                instance.likes.add(request.user)
            else:
                instance.likes.remove(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
        except:
            pass
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'ko'})
```

**Model**

`likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')`

I also tried using this jquery via cdn `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` but it doesnt make the like button work at all.